# VNC Server using different GUI to localmachine?

Tags: solaris, vnc, graphical-user-interface

When I started a VNCServer instance on my machine it seems to be using an older version of Solaris GUI. However when I go down to the server room and login locally to the machine I get a nice newer version of Solaris 10 desktop and GUI

**On VNC Viewer**

[image]

**On Local Machine**

[image]

I am guessing this is a config problem, where should I look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X session startup commands run by VNC are generally found in `~/.vnc/xstartup`.

Your top screenshot looks like the old default X session of xterm & twm.

To start the GNOME desktop instead, you can insert a call to run it if it’s available, such as:

```
#!/bin/sh

vncconfig -iconic &

if [ -x /usr/dt/config/Xsession.jds ]; then
  exec /usr/dt/config/Xsession.jds
fi
[ -r \$HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb \$HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title \"\$VNCDESKTOP Desktop\" &
twm &
```

(I've not tried this on Solaris 10 myself, but have using the much newer versions of VNC & GNOME in Solaris 11, though that uses different commands to start GNOME 2.30.)